# Why does nearly everyone use .h-files instead of .hpp-files in C++-Projects nowadays?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I just wondered why most people use the .h extension in their C++ Projects, even though the standard is actually .hpp?
Isn't this a little stupid? I always thought precision in differencing between those is important?

Comment: OK, let's test your premise for a moment.  Will C++ projects that use `.h` instead of `.hpp` *still compile?*

Comment: In most cases it will, but if you have a mixed C/C++-Project with wrappers, there are problems coming upon you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/152555

Comment: And [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/3jdjec/is_there_a_difference_between_h_and_hpp_and/): *"C++ itself doesn't actually care about file extensions. C used .h for header files. This convention has been used for C++ as well, and is perfectly acceptable, especially since it's very common to use C header files in C++ code anyway. But the reverse isn't true: you can't generally use a C++ header file in C code, so a convention of using the .hpp file extension makes it clear that it's a C++ header file and **shouldn't be used by a C program.**"*

Comment: Why do you think that the standard is .hpp? The C++ standard doesn't prescribe it. And as (quote) "most people use the .h extension," one could argue that the de-facto standard actually is to use the .h extension.

Comment: Most projects that are implemented in C++ do not need to be concerned about being usable (consumable) by C projects - a lot of advantage in having a C++ API is that it can do things that a C API couldn't do, or would have required extremely complex machinery, such as generics (template), type-safety on opaque types, etc. An example is OpenCV, most new functionality are no longer available on C API anymore. In other words, confining a C++ project to have a C-compatible interface could kill the main motivation (advantage) for using C++ over C.

Comment: If you are interested in providing a C callable interface for your C++ API, please read about "hourglass interface". For programmers who work on Microsoft, there is "component object model", and there is a similar Linux clone that is called "XPCOM" (cross platform component object model).

Comment: It may be worth noting that at least at one point, one common convention used on systems with case-senstitive filenames was to use `.c` and  `.h` for C files and `.C` and `.H` for C++ files.  Some of those projects you see using `.h` may instead be using `.H`.

Answer (score 5):

Your premise that .hpp is standard is wrong. There is nothing in the C++ standard that says so. You yourself observe that

> [..] most people use the .h extension in their C++ Projects [..]

Therefore the de facto standard is to use the .h extension; There is no de jure standard.

To answer your question: **people use the .h extension because it is the de facto standard.**

Answer (score 2):

.h is used as the extension for header files in C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++. I often use header files that will work just fine in some or all of these languages - sometimes by using plain C, carefully checked to be written in a subset compatible with the other languages, sometimes by using compile-time checks to adapt to the language.